# 'powf' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, std

I have an error while compiling a library using XCode:

> ```
> 'powf' is not a member of 'std'
> ```

The `<cmath>` is included.

Can someone explain to me what is going wrong?

Comment: As of June 2019, the C++17 standard explicitly states that `<cmath>` declares `powf` (as well as `sinf`, `logf`, etc.) within `namespace std`, but libstdc++ is still buggy. See [this question about C++17.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458487/stdexpf-and-stdlogf-not-recognized-by-gcc-7-2-0)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's 10 years and 4 C++ versions old; the answers are mostly of the form "That's not standard C++03"; it's just no longer helpful on the site IMHO.

Comment: I think it should be kept open. g++ (e.g. version 11.2.0, standard on Ubuntu 22.04) **still** doesn't seem to have the function, despite it being standard since C++11...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Up until C++11, `powf` was just a [Microsoft-ism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt5dakze%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It did not appear in the ISO standard at all so is unlikely to be in XCode unless they were to adapt Microsoft's bizarre practices, something I would think unlikely.

`pow`, on the other hand, has been part of the C++ library for longer by virtue of the fact that it's in earlier iterations of the C library that is incorporated into C++ pre-11. Use that instead.

Since C++11, `powf` *does* appear in the ISO standard and is part of the `std` namespace.

Nevertheless, there are non-compliant implementations e.g., gcc libstdc++. More resources in this excerpt taken from a discussion in [cppreference talk page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:Main_Page/suggestions):

> Answers posted above were correct before C++11, since C++98/03 hadn't referred C99 library yet. According to the [current standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/cmath.syn), `powf` is declared in namespace `std` when  is included (explicitly mentioned since C++17, implicitly mentioned in C++11/14, see also [N4659](https://wg21.link/N4659), [N4140](https://wg21.link/N4140) and [N3337](https://wg21.link/N3337)). For `std::powf`, gcc libstdc++ is not compliant while [clang libc++ is](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L71HDnQlFQezXPDA). --Fruderica (talk) 03:49, 19 February 2019 (PST)
>
> See also this, more recent, SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54735351 --Cubbi (talk) 08:10, 19 February 2019 (PST)

Answer (score 4):

Use just `pow` - `powf` isn't standard.

Answer (score 3):

It is named `std::pow` and overloaded for `float` and `double`.