# Is fabsf part of the std namespace in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, cmath

The page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs mentions that `std::fabsf` is available since C++11. However, when I use G++ 6.3.0 to compile even the simplest program that uses `std::fabsf`, it says that `fabsf` is not a member of `std`.

```
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    return (int)std::fabsf(0.0f);
}
```

Which one is right? Is G++ 6.3.0 wrong in not including it in `std`, or is the above page wrong in mentioning it as part of `std` in C++11?

And if it's G++ that is wrong, is that fixed in later versions?

Comment: What compiler options are you using?

Comment: I assume that you used the compiler flag -std=c++11 or -std=c++0x...?

Comment: C++17 is the first standard version that explicitly mentions `fabsf`

Comment: @melpomene only -std=c++11. RHertel yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `fabsf` and all other `-f`/`-l` functions from `math.h` is part of the `std` namespace via `cmath` in C++11. It was added in about 2002, when C++0x was rebased on top of the C99 standard library, which made `[c.math]/4` include those new functions.

> `[c.math]/4`
>
> The contents of these headers are the same as the Standard C library headers `<math.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` respectively, with the following changes:

(historical note: the intent to add all the `-f`/`-l` variants was already apparent in C++03, see [LWG289](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue289))

However, the table listing the contents of cmath was overlooked until 2016, when
[p0175r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0175r1.html) fixed all such tables to bring them in line with the standard.

> `p0175r1`
>
> **Impact on the standard**
>
> The change is purely editorial.

Comment: Are we saying this is a toolchain bug that's a result of an editorial oversight?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like cppreference is incorrect. It appears this was added for C++17 since it was [added to the draft in 2016](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/1bd91614433e22c754419292b881cd092afffc1c) with the title `[numerics] Apply P0175 (C Synopses)` and we can see [p0175r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0175r1.html) does indeed add:

```
 float fabsf(float x);
```

The [libc++ status](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html) does not indicate a status for `p0175r1` so that would indicate that it does not support these changes yet. I can't find a line item for the proposal in [tjhe libstdc++ status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html).

Comment: That's very well researched and documented, thank you.

Comment: Don't overlook C++11's [c.math]/4

Comment: P0175 is a purely editorial paper with no normative effect. Also what Cubbi said.