# `cosf`, `sinf`, etc. are not in `std`

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

**Based on the discussion here, I have [reported a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-8/+bug/1831385) to the Ubuntu developers.**

---

When compiling the following sample c++ program:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", std::cosf(0.0f));
}
```

I get the following error message: `error: ‘cosf’ is not a member of ‘std’`

Including `math.h` and using the non-namespaced version works fine. What is going on?

I am using g++ 8.3.0-6ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 19.04.

I am building with `g++ --std=c++17 test.cpp`

Comment: What's your compilation command?  Just a bare `g++ main.cpp`?

Comment: I think `std::sinf`, `std::cosf` etc were added in C++11. Are you compiling with C++11 enabled?

Comment: g++ --std=c++17 main.cpp

Comment: FWIW I can repro using Debian Buster's `g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0`.

Comment: `cosf` works in 8.3/9.1 per quick test on godbolt with `--std=c++17`; `std::cosf` works in neither.  (Just a quick observation).

Comment: I tried with `cosh` and works btw.

Comment: A bug in GCC? in Visual Studio it works correctly.

Comment: On Godbolt, this gives an error when using g++ or clang with libstdc++. It works when using clang -stdlib=libc++.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug to Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-8/+bug/1831385

Comment: Also report it upstream, to the libstdc++ maintainers at GNU?

Comment: @Davislor I don't want to waste their time without knowing whether this is a deb or ubuntu patch, or an upstream issue. I think Ubuntu devs will triage it to upstream if appropriate.

Comment: C++ overloads `std::cos()` for `float`... you don't need `std::cosf()`.

Comment: @Shawn It’s required to be there by C++17, so the library is lagging the standard by a couple of years.

Comment: @BrennanVincent Regardless of this being a bug or not, you can just drop the `std::`. The compiler still finds the right `cosf` by [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) The upshot being, that it also works when you replace the float with a custom type (with a custom `cosf`). See https://godbolt.org/z/cWlDgC for an example.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700

Comment: ['powf' is not a member of 'std'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483930/powf-is-not-a-member-of-std); [std::expf and std::logf not recognized by gcc 7.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458487/stdexpf-and-stdlogf-not-recognized-by-gcc-7-2-0); [Is fabsf part of the std namespace in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027717/is-fabsf-part-of-the-std-namespace-in-c11)

Comment: The fact that GNU has ignored this bug for two years suggests to me that Ubuntu was, in fact, the correct people to report it to. They can patch it downstream and fix it for their users without intervention from GNU.

Comment: @cpplearner I’ve copied the accepted answer from here over to the earlier question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That version of the library ([libstdc++8](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/libstdc++/api/a01119.html)) is not fully conforming to C++17.  The copyright notice says it was last updated in 2016.  As of June 2019, [the latest upstream release](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/libstdc++/api/a00215_source.html) is bugged.  It does have a `#if __cplusplus > 201402L` section, but it doesn’t declare the identifiers required by C++17.  [There is an open bug report.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700)

Looking at `/usr/include/c++/8/cmath` on Ubuntu, it includes `<math.h>`, undefines a series of macros for its functions (required by the C standard library) to access their names, imports `cos`, `acos`, etc. into the `std::` namespace, and then declares the overloaded `float` and `long double` overloads as `inline`.

It never declares `cosf` within the `std::` namespace, even though [C++17 says it shall.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf#subsection.29.9.1)  The [C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) says, “Names that are defined as functions in C shall be defined as functions in the C++ standard library,” and “Each name from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with `extern "C"` linkage, both in `namespace std` and in the global namespace.”  However, it does not explicitly state that `std::expf` et al. must be supported until [P0175r1 in June 2016.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0175r1.html)  This was apparently an oversight.

The [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/cmath) library does declare them, so compiling with `clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++` should work.

Comment: It's only a _bug_ if it _should_ be there.  Can you justify that?

Comment: @HWalters please see the C++17 standard, draft N4659, (final freely available draft), page 1140.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf

Comment: @BrennanVincent Thanks. Added your citation.

Comment: @Davislor ...are you sure _C++11_ specifes this?  This is why I asked earlier... I was thumbing through my 11 standard and it doesn't seem it requires `cosf` in the `std` namespace (a search for `cosf` doesn't even turn up anything).  It _does_ say that `<cmath>` includes `math.h`, but it just lists three overloads of `cos`.

Comment: @HWalters Let me check. Cppreference said so.

Comment: @HWalters So now I’m not sure myself.  The N3337 working draft has no such requirement, but [cppreference.com claims they’ve been there since C++11.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math) Was that a last-minute change, or is the website in error?

Comment: @Davislor Section 26.8, C library, of the published standard looks very much like the N3337 draft to me; no big surprises there.  (But I only own an official C++11, well, and a 2003).

Comment: @HWalters Thanks. I’ll edit my answer to note that this behavior conforms to C++11.

Comment: In C++11 (N3337) it says "The contents of these headers are the same as the Standard C library headers `<math.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` repsctively, with the following changes:"  .  The C version does contain `cosf` (added in C99, which is what is meant by "Standard C" in C++11) and the "following changes" don't say anything that would exclude cosf.  I think it is just an oversight that cosf was not listed in the Table 119.

Comment: @M.M My reading of C++11 is that it does require `<cmath>` to declare `::cosf` et al. in the global namespace, as `<math.h>` does, and it requires `std::cosf` et al. to be reserved, but it makes the declaration of `std::cosf` optional—and GCC has never done so. C++17 is completely unambiguous.

Comment: @M.M cppreference.com [agrees with your interpretation of C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math) and disagrees with GCC’s.

Comment: @Davislor cppreference is a wiki anyone can edit , its not an authoritative source

Comment: @M.M Indeed. Nevertheless, it agrees with you, although that won’t make code that follows it compile with GCC or all settings of Clang++.