# std::expf and std::logf not recognized by gcc 7.2.0

Tags: c++11, gcc

It seems that gcc (tried 7.2.0 and 5.4.0) does not have [std::expf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/exp) and [std::logf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log]) - see coliru [sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93e7783855aa4ce9). Since cppreference says they were added in C++11 is there some gcc specific macro I am missing or are they in general missing in gcc?

Comment: what is your g++ commandline? you need to add `-std=c++11` to enable c++11

Comment: @Nidhoegger I did have the flags on my machine, but did not add them to coliru, fixed the sample, but the flags do not solve that since I had them from very start.

Comment: There’s been [an open bug report on this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700) for two years. The C++17 standard requires `<cmath>` to declare `std::expf`, `std::logf`, etc., but libstdc++ is not conforming (as of June 2019). See [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417980/cosf-sinf-etc-are-not-in-std/56418143#56417980)

Comment: The libc++ implementation does declare the identifiers correctly, so `clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++` should work.

Comment: See also [`cosf`, `sinf`, etc are not in `std::`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417980/cosf-sinf-etc-are-not-in-std_).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in libstdc++, which ships with GCC.  It does not fully conform to C++17 ([as of v9.1.0 in June 2019](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/libstdc++/api/a00215_source.html)).  The copyright notice on the version of `<cmath>` that Ubuntu uses by default says it was last updated in 2016.  Version 9.1.0 does have a `#if __cplusplus > 201402L` section, but it doesn’t declare the identifiers required by C++17.  [There is an open bug report.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700)

It never declares `expf` or `logf` (nor `cosf`, `sinf`, etc.) within the `std::` namespace, even though [C++17 says it shall.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf#subsection.29.9.1)  The [C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) says, “Names that are defined as functions in C shall be defined as functions in the C++ standard library,” and “Each name from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with `extern "C"` linkage, both in `namespace std` and in the global namespace.”  However, `std::expf` et al. are missing from the table of functions provided by `<cmath>` until [P0175r1 in June 2016.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0175r1.html) This was apparently an oversight, but GCC has always made them available only in the global namespace.

The [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/cmath) library does declare them, so compiling with `clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++` should work.  You can also `#include <math.h>` to use them in the global namespace, or use the overloaded `exp()`, `log()`, etc. on float arguments.

##### Update

[As of version 13.2,](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00275_source.html) the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you

```
#include <cmath>
```

you will get

```
float       exp ( float arg );
double      exp ( double arg );
long double exp ( long double arg );
double      exp ( IntegralType arg );

float       log ( float arg );
double      log ( double arg );
long double log ( long double arg );
double      log ( IntegralType arg );
```

And hence you can call just `std::exp`/`std::log` and let the compiler figure out the overload for you. If you want to call a mismatching overload (e.g. the `float` overload on a `double` variable), I find it much more explicit and clear to add a `static_cast` in those cases:

```
double bla = ...;
return std::exp(static_cast<float>(bla));
```

This is a strange construct any way you write it (e.g. why is `bla` not a `float` to begin with?), and hiding it in a single-letter function name suffix isn't helping anyone.

Comment: Ok, that is a valid fallback, simply msvc and clang accepted expf and logf just fine:(

Comment: Good tip on the fallback, appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

GCC's `<cmath>` declares the functions `expf` and `logf` and their C Library kin in the
global namespace, not `std::`. In `std::` it declares overloads of `exp` and `log` to
the same effect.